# How to validate animation(gif exists or not) on mobile app+appium+android

Tags: android, animation, mobile, appium, animated-gif

I get an animation and will go away on my mobile app.
I need to validate it

Comment: Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a gif with different images i recomend use this tutorial

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm

Comment: Hi dpart, thanks very much for your prompt suggestion but i am very new to this and i really need to know how to validate whether the animation exists/happened  or not  on the mobile app screen and there is no way that i can capture it as an element. so please let me know how to validate. please send me a sample code.  Thanks in advance

Comment: could anyone please help me?